# How to keep map marker icons move when zooming in/out of map

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-development, fluttermap

I am using [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map) in my app to show a map with Markers on it.

The issue I'm having is that when I zoom in/out, ***the Markers move, as opposed to staying rooted to their location.*** I have a CircleMarker around each Marker and it becomes obvious very quickly that they're not centered correctly (see images below).

How to correctly anchor the Marker icon so that it doesn't move around when I zoom in/out of the map?

**Up close Marker:**

[image]

**Zoomed out Marker:**

[image]

**Zoomed out even farther Marker:**

[image]

My code for making the Markers:

```
  Marker marker = Marker(
  point:
      LatLng(alertLatitude, alertLongitude),
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  anchorPos: AnchorPos.align(AnchorAlign.center),
  builder: (context) => Icon(
        Icons.location_on_sharp,
        size: 60,
        color: Color(aquarium),
      ));
```

My code for making the FlutterMap:

```
FlutterMap(
      mapController: _mapController,
      options: MapOptions(
        center: determineMapStartLocation(),
        zoom: 14,
        plugins: [MarkerClusterPlugin()],
        onTap: (_, __) => _popupController.hideAllPopups(),
      ),
      layers: [
        TileLayerOptions(
          minZoom: 1,
          maxZoom: 20,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          urlTemplate: 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
          subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
        ),
        CircleLayerOptions(
          circles: alertCirclesList,
        ),
        MarkerClusterLayerOptions(
          maxClusterRadius: 190,
          disableClusteringAtZoom: 12,
          size: Size(90, 90),
          fitBoundsOptions: FitBoundsOptions(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(50),
          ),
          markers: _alertMarkers,
          ...
        )]);
```

Answer (score 2):

looks like your alignment is off

```dart
  Marker marker = Marker(
  point:
      LatLng(alertLatitude, alertLongitude),
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  anchorPos: AnchorPos.align(AnchorAlign.bottom/*AnchorAlign.center*/), //change center to bottom
  builder: (context) => Icon(
        Icons.location_on_sharp,
        size: 60,
        color: Color(aquarium),
      ));
```

if this isnt exactly working i'd fiddle with `AnchorPos.exact(Anchor(left:x,right:y))` until it seems right

Comment: Thank you, best answer so far. This definitely helps, but they still slip a bit. I added anchorPos: AnchorPos.align(AnchorAlign.top)

Answer (score 0):

I tried using [google_maps_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/google_maps_flutter), I hope it will help.

Used marker with position params.

```
Marker(markerId: MarkerId((i).toString()),
  position: LatLng(double.parse(data[i].latitude ?? '0'), 
  double.parse(data[i].longitude ?? '0')));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I'm fortunately using the open source flutter_maps in the meantime!